# How to target children in a each loop using GreenSock and ScrollMagic

Tags: javascript, gsap, scrollmagic

I want to be able to have each div with the class of .fade-in target its children h1(slide in right) and span(slide in left) by using a each() loop. So my question is how do I target a child element using 'this' e.g `tl.from('.fade-in h1', 1, {x: 300})` Replace .fade-in with "this"?

```
tl
  .from(
    ".fade-in h1",
    0.3,
    { autoAlpha: 0, scale: 0.5, x: 300, ease: Linear.easeNone },
    "x"
  )
  .from(
    ".fade-in span",
    0.3,
    { autoAlpha: 0, scale: 0.5, x: -300, color: "red", ease: Linear.easeNone },
    "x"
  );
```

[**Demo Link**](https://codepen.io/Armandot6/pen/jaLZXG?editors=1010)

Comment: Also, I'm new. But why is it so hard to add some code on here. Am I doing something wrong? Terrible UI/UX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Check Demo [**Here**](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/MOvVVL?editors=1100)

```
// init controller
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

// loop through all elements
$(".fade-in").each(function() {
  var jh1 = $(this).find("h1");
  var jspan = $(this).find("span");
  var tl = new TimelineMax();

  tl
    .from(
      jh1,
      0.5,
      { autoAlpha: 0, scale: 0.5, x: 300, ease: Linear.easeNone },
      "x"
    )
    .from(
      jspan,
      0.5,
      {
        autoAlpha: 0,
        scale: 0.5,
        x: -300,
        color: "red",
        ease: Linear.easeNone
      },
      "x"
    );

  // build a scene
  var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: this,
    offset: 10,
    triggerHook: 0
  })
    .setTween(tl) // trigger a TweenMax.to tween
    .addIndicators()
    .addTo(controller);
});
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! And thanks for cleaning up my question, you're awesome.